# running joblib.Parallel(mlxtend) does not scale in cloud-ml

Tags: parallel-processing, google-cloud-ml, joblib

Im running a job using the `mlxtend` library. Specifically the `sequential_feature_selector` that is parallelized using `joblib.Parallel` [source](https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend/blob/master/mlxtend/feature_selection/sequential_feature_selector.py#L23). When I run the package on my local computer it uses all the  available CPUs, but when i send the job to `cloud-ml` it only uses one core. It doesn't matter what is the number that i put in the `n_jobs` parameter. I´ve also tried with differents machine types but same thing happen. 
Does anybody know what the problem might be ?

Comment: We don't put any restriction on number of cores.  Can you share your job id and repro with us via cloudml-feedback@google.com please?

Comment: Hi @GuoqingXu Im trying to reproduce the error with a sample code, I will add it to the question as soon as I have it. Thanks !!

Comment: Thanks @GuoqingXu finally it was a problem with the sklearn version, fixing the version in the package setup fixed the problem

Comment: Good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that might be interested, we solve the problem fixing the `sklearn` version in the `setup.py` to the `0.20.2`. we had `sklearn` in the packages before, but without a version.

```
#setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['joblib==0.13.0',
                     'scikit-learn==0.20.2',
                     'mlxtend']
```